# Go and JWT - Simple authentication

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I'm currently making an API (with go) and I'm working on the session part.
After research about  what to use for session, I found JWT really interesting.

However I'm not really sure to understand how to use it after some tutorials.
So this is my idea:

```
func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    router.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    router.HandleFunc("/logout", logout)
    router.HandleFunc("/register", register)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)

 }
```

After those  requests handled, I create the differents functions.

```
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    Here I just have to search in my database (SQL, I know how to do it). If the user is registered, I create a token and give it to him, but how can I do it?                                           
    */
 }

 func logout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    I get a token and stop/delete it?                                                                                                                                                                    
    */
 }

 func register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    I search if the user isn't register and then, if it isn't, I create a user in the database (I know how to do it). I connect him but again, how to make a new token?                                  
    */
 }
```

Lot of tutorials on the web seems really hard but I just want something simple. I just want an handle package (code above) which work with a service package to have something like an engine token authentication.

A second point I'm not sure to understand is the saving of the token.
If a user connects himself, then what would be best? Each time the user runs their app, the app connects itself and get a new token from saved information (user/password) or the app just save the token forever? And what about the server, is the token managed and saved automatically with JWT or do I have to put it in my sql database?

Thank for your help !

**EDIT 1**

Thank you ! So after I read your answer, I encapsulated my code (token.go) like it

```
package services

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "time"
    "../models"
)

var tokenEncodeString string = "something"

func createToken(user models.User) (string, error) {
    // create the token                                                                                                                                                                                  
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)

    // set some claims                                                                                                                                                                                   
    token.Claims["username"] = user.Username;
    token.Claims["password"] = user.Password;
    token.Claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()

    //Sign and get the complete encoded token as string                                                                                                                                                  
    return (token.SignedString(tokenEncodeString))
}

func parseToken(unparsedToken string) (bool, string) {
    token, err := jwt.Parse(unparsedToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            // Don't forget to validate the alg is what you expect:                                                                                                                                      
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
            }
            return myLookupKey(token.Header["kid"]), nil
    })

    if err == nil && token.Valid {
            return true, unparsedToken
    } else {
            return false, ""
    }
 }
```

However, I got the following error: "token.go: undefined: myLookupKey"
I looked on internet and I found an encapsulated function which have this prototype:

```
func ExampleParse(myToken string, myLookupKey func(interface{}) (interface{}, error)) {
 /* same code in my func parseToken() */
}
```

So what are the difference between my function and this one? How can I use this one?

Thanks !

Comment: The code example using a Claims map doesn't work. The API may have changed in the mean time.

Comment: I have no idea honestly :/ I did long time ago and today I changed of work so.. :/

Comment: Storing the password in the token claims is not recommended, the token cookie isn't encrypted, the user can read it

Comment: Just commenting to add that `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` is now depricated and contains unresolved CVEs. People should now use `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt` instead.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note:
This package **github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go** is deprecated use this instead **github.com/golang-jwt/jwt**

To start, you need to import a JWT library in Golang (go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go). You can find that library documentation in below link.

https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go

Firstly, you need to create a token

```
// Create the token
token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
// Set some claims
token.Claims["foo"] = "bar"
token.Claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()
// Sign and get the complete encoded token as a string
tokenString, err := token.SignedString(mySigningKey)
```

Secondly, parse that token

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(myToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    // Don't forget to validate the alg is what you expect:
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    }
    return myLookupKey(token.Header["kid"]), nil
})

if err == nil && token.Valid {
    deliverGoodness("!")
} else {
    deliverUtterRejection(":(")
}
```

Also, there are some examples for use JWT in GOlang like this https://github.com/slok/go-jwt-example

EDIT-1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

const (
    mySigningKey = "WOW,MuchShibe,ToDogge"
)

func main() {
    createdToken, err := ExampleNew([]byte(mySigningKey))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Creating token failed")
    }
    ExampleParse(createdToken, mySigningKey)
}

func ExampleNew(mySigningKey []byte) (string, error) {
    // Create the token
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
    // Set some claims
    token.Claims["foo"] = "bar"
    token.Claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()
    // Sign and get the complete encoded token as a string
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(mySigningKey)
    return tokenString, err
}

func ExampleParse(myToken string, myKey string) {
    token, err := jwt.Parse(myToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(myKey), nil
    })

    if err == nil && token.Valid {
        fmt.Println("Your token is valid.  I like your style.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("This token is terrible!  I cannot accept this.")
    }
}
```

Comment: After jwt-go this solution is broken. Please update the answer.

Comment: Just commenting to add that `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` is now depricated and contains unresolved CVEs. People should now use `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Just to make update of @massoud-afrashteh answer.
In version 3 of jwt-go setting clams should be

```
// Set some claims
claims := make(jwt.MapClaims)
claims["foo"] = "bar"
claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()
token.Claims = claims
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to run the command `go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`.

Another way to create more simple:

```
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
   "foo": "bar",
   "nbf": time.Date(2015, 10, 10, 12, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix(),
})
tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte("your key"))
fmt.Println(tokenString, err)
```

Comment: Just commenting to add that `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` is now depricated and contains unresolved CVEs. People should now use `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
func GenerateToken(mySigningKey []byte, username string) (string, error) {
    // Create the token
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodRS512)
    claims := make(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims[collections.PARAM_USER_NAME] = username
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()
    token.Claims = claims
    return token.SignedString(mySigningKey)
}
```